# Is "~" handled differently in Bash Script string vars?

Tags: git, directory, sh, git-bash

Okay,
I have a simple script that takes each line from a txt file and treats it like a folder path.
The script, using pushd, changes directory into the folder and runs a GIT bash command (or series of commands if desired).

So i can do something like this from the GIT bash prompt:

```
runcmd -c "git status" -f mydirs.txt
```

And I'll get what changed in all of the repositories listed in the txt file.

Problem:
I put this in the mydirs.txt:

```
~/Shared/MyLibrary
~/Shared/MyOtherLibrary 
~/Apps/MyApplication
```

Now in GIT bash, the "~" is synonymous with "home".  So if my home path is /e/dev/projects, regardless of any folder I'm in, I type "cd ~" and I'm back in e/dev/projects.

Question:
Does the bash shell script processor interpret the ~ differently between when it is a string in a variable versus being typed at the prompt?

Here is the script that is being run:

```
for (( l=0; l<${#lines[@]}; l++ )) 
do
    line=${lines[$l]} 
    printf "pushd $line\n"
    pushd $line #>/dev/null
    if [[ $(echo $?) == 0 ]]; then
        for (( i=0; i<${#cmds[@]}; i++ )) 
        do
            eval "${cmds[$i]}"
        done
        popd > /dev/null
            
    else printf "  \e[1;31mERROR\e[0m: Directory \e[1;36m%s\e[0m does not exist!\n"  $line
    fi; 
done
```

(yes it's incomplete, but it's the "pushd $line" that keeps failing saying there is no such directory)

if i change it to the fully expanded path without the ~, it works.
So, can I get the interpreter to process the "~" a variable the same as when i type it on the command line?

Comment: `$(echo $?)` ?? It's like `$(echo $(echo $(echo $?))))`. It's just `$?` | `in, I type "cd ~"` - no need to type `~`. Just type `cd` and you'll go to home.

Comment: `~`, like all other shell syntax including `$HOME` and `$(pwd)`, is not evaluated in literal string data. Replace it yourself with string operations.

Comment: Search for "tilde expansion" in `man bash` for explanation.

Comment: Exercise: explain why you used `eval` in the inner loop, then think about what `eval pushd $line` might do. Or: what would `eval expanded=$line` do? What if `$line` contains glob patterns like `*`, or contains whitespace characters?